# how to give time gap between two activities in android?

Tags: android

This is my code.I used one one popup message while clicking on button for that i used Toast after that i want to move next screen

```
Button Replybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Reply);
        Replybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
          public void onClick(View v) 
          {

               EditText ReplysubjeditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ReplysubjeditText);
               EditText ReplymsgeditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ReplymsgeditText);  
               String temp_string=ReplysubjeditText.getText().toString();

         try 
             {

                ReplysubjeditText.setText("");
                ReplymsgeditText.setText("");


              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                Log.v("Add",e.toString());
              }

              Toast.makeText(EmailReply.this, "Sending....",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Intent myNewMail = new Intent(EmailReply.this,EmailForm.class);
                myNewMail.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                startActivity(myNewMail);


          }
           });
```

Comment: Or you can try using the Toast on the OnCreate() of the next activity. This might work out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure diplaying a Toast is the right choice here? IMO and per your description, you need a modal dialog.

However, to answer your question, one of the ways of adding a delay is by suspending a thread for some time(Thread.sleep). Though, I would advise strictly against it.